# Can I consider Multiple Row values as one in a group by clause?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Col1  Col2
A     ...
A     ...
A
B
B
C
D
```

I want to be able to consider A & B as if they were one for the purposes of group by, so that

```
select Col1, count(*) from table group by Col1
```

will return

```
Col1  count(*)
AB    5
C     1
D     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group on a conditional column via a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Col1 IN ('A','B') THEN 'AB' ELSE Col1 END AS Col1Group,
  COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN Col1 IN ('A','B') THEN 'AB' ELSE Col1 END
```

You did not specify your RDBMS, but some (like MySQL) will permit you to use the alias `Col1Group` inside the `GROUP BY` rather than having to duplicate the whole expression down there.